# How to add Kivy list view padding between rows

Tags: python, kivy

Is it possible to apply vertical padding between rows on a Kivy list view? I have tried modifying the kv file padding on both the list view and the gridlayout to no avail.

```
+++++++
+ Row +  
+++++++
+ Pad +
+++++++
+ Row +
+++++++
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will add padding between the ListView items by using a ListAdapter and list_items_arg_converter where you can modify the look of your ListItems. It does not change the padding of the underlying GridLayout but just changes the height of the items.

Hope this helps,
Cheers

[Kivy        ] v1.9.1
[Python      ] v2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:32:19) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.adapters.dictadapter import ListAdapter
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.listview import ListView, ListItemButton
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.app import App

from random import randint


class MyApp(App):
    items = 20
    pad = 20
    space = 20
    text_border = 10

    def build(self):
        mainlayout = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical')
        self.list_adapter = ListAdapter(data = ["Item #{0}".format(i) for i in range(self.items)], cls = ListItemButton,
                                        args_converter=self.list_item_args_converter, sorted_keys = [])
        self.list_view = ListView(adapter=self.list_adapter, size_hint_y=.3)
        self.list_view.container.padding = self.pad
        self.list_view.container.spacing = self.space
        mainlayout.add_widget(self.list_view)
        return mainlayout

    def list_item_args_converter(self,col,obj):
        return {
            'text': obj,
            'size_hint_y': .3,
            'text_size' : (self.root.width-2*self.pad-2*self.text_border , None),
            'height': 32,
            'halign': 'left',
            'valign': 'middle',
            'deselected_color':[.5,.5,.5,1],
            'selected_color':[1.,1.,1.,1]
        }


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: The problem is you cannot scroll to item 20, would you know how to fix?

Comment: I changed the code. Scrolling does work now (as it should have in the first place ...sorry).  The background of the items has to be black with this solution. I coudn't figure out how to fix scrolling after changing the padding of the underlying gridlayout ...

Comment: I think the problem with your previous solution was: "You must carefully specify the size_hint of your content to get the desired scroll/pan effect." From the scroll view documentation, which is the parent of the grid layout

Comment: I think the problem was that I changed the padding of the GridLayout (which worked...) after the overlying ScrollView already calculated its overscoll distance with the initial GridLayout.... the size of the GridLayout is correct (you can see the whole grid when you try to overscroll). Scrolling just bounces back because the ScrollView thinks it is scrolling the initial GridLaout without padding .... I could not figure out where to set the correct values ...